# How to double click at a cursor position

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to double click at a cursor position but I may be missing something.

```
Public Declare Auto Function SetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Long
Public Declare Auto Function GetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByRef lpPoint As Point) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2 ' left button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4 ' left button up

SetCursorPos(2681,792)
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include the API import portion of the code, as these aren't .NET functions.

Comment: Have you actually defined those functions and constants?

Comment: Updated to show what was requested.

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what problems you are having with the limited amount of information you posted. See my answer I think will help

Comment: The problem is the code is not double clicking. I have a series of set cursors and left click codes leading up to this one. They all work properly, clicking the correct buttons in another window. However, this double click code is a specific piece of text. I am trying to double click the text to highlight it, then use sendkeys to copy the highlighted text. The problem is, the double click code is not double clicking the text and highlighting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import the proper API functions and set your constants.

```
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" Alias "SetCursorPos" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Boolean
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "User32.dll" Alias "mouse_event" (dwFlags As UInt32, dx As UInt32, dy As UInt32, dwData As UInt32, dwExtraInfo As Int32)

Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE As UInt32 = &HE8000
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As UInt32 = &HE0002
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As UInt32 = &HE0004
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL As UInt32 = &HE1000
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN As UInt32 = &HE0020
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP As UInt32 = &HE0040
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE As UInt32 = &HE0001
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As UInt32 = &HE0008
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As UInt32 = &HE0010
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL As UInt32 = &HE0800
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN As UInt32 = &HE0080
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_XUP As UInt32 = &HE0100

Sub Main()
    SetCursorPos(2681, 792)
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

This was all found in MSDN documentation:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/172wfck9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function apimouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Int32, ByVal dX As Int32, ByVal dY As Int32, ByVal cButtons As Int32, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Int32) As Boolean
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As Integer = 2
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Integer = 4
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Integer = 8
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Integer = 16

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' move cursor to 200,200 and double-click
        move_and_dblclick(200, 200)
    End Sub

    Private Sub move_and_dblclick(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(x, y)
        apimouse_event((MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN Or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP), x, y, 0, 0)
        Thread.Sleep(150)
        apimouse_event((MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN Or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP), x, y, 0, 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```