# Attempting to simulate mouse down, yet getting stack unbalance error. Possibly to do with incorrect variables?

Tags: vb.net, basic

I'm building a desktop application in VB.Net which needs to simulate mouse presses in other applications. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2 ' left button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4 ' left button up
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20 ' middle button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40 ' middle button up
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8 ' right button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10 ' right button up
```

Now, when I'm calling it, I do this:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0, 0)
```

However, I'm getting the error message:

> a call to PInvoke function has unbalanced the stack

I've done some research and I believe I understand what it means, but I can't seem to fix it.

I've tried doing Long.Parse(value) on all of my Integer values, yet I still get the error.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

If you need more info, then let me know!!

- Visual Studio 2010
- VB.NET 4.5

Comment: Your API call looks VB6-ish.  See [How to double click at a cursor position](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24291099/719186)

Comment: I know haha, it is quite VB6-ish. I haven't found a way to convert it to VB.Net fully, I tried my best though!

Comment: @LarsTech That fixed it! Thank you so much :D

Comment: @MorganLane if that author in that linked helped, please help by upvoting it..

Comment: @Zaggler Done, I'm new to SO :)

Comment: @MorganLane thank you and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was it was very VB6-y.

Here's the updated code.

```
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "User32.dll" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As UInt32, ByVal dx As UInt32, ByVal dy As UInt32, ByVal dwData As UInt32, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Int32)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As UInt32 = &HE0002
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As UInt32 = &HE0004
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As UInt32 = &HE0008
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As UInt32 = &HE0010
```

Thanks to LarsTech